# How can I update a line drawn in pygame

Tags: python, math, pygame, line, drawing

I was trying to draw a function with a tangent for each value of `x`
I tried drawing a white line over the tangent after it displays, but the tangent didn't show.

The problem:
[the tangent gets drawn all under the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQftT.png)

the code:

```
import pygame
import os
from math import *
from time import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

os.system('cls')
fun = True
x = -300
y = 0
xl = [0, 0]
yl = [0, 0]
ys = 0
xs = -300
xsl = [0, 0]
ysl = [0, 0]
al = 0
slobe = 0

while True:
    if x <= 600 and fun:
        if x == -1:
            x = 1
        yl[0] = y
        y = 0.001 * x**2
        y = -y
        yl[1] = y

        xl[0] = x
        x += 1
        xl[1] = x
        print((x, y), xl, yl)

        pygame.draw.line(screen, 'red', (xl[0] + 300, yl[0] + 300), (xl[1] + 300, yl[1] + 300))

    if x > 600 and fun:
        fun = False
        x = -300

    if not fun:
        y = 0.001 * x**2
        y = -y

        if x == -1:
            x = 1

        x += 1
        slobe = 0.002 * x
        xs = -300
        for i in range(600):
            point = (x, y)

            xsl[0] = xs
            xs += 1
            xsl[1] = xs

            al = xs + point[0]

            ysl[0] = ys
            ys = slobe * al + y + 3
            ysl[1] = ys

            pygame.draw.line(screen, 'white', (xsl[0] + 300, ysl[0] + 300), (xsl[1] + 300, ysl[1] + 300))
            pygame.draw.line(screen, 'blue', (xsl[0] + 300, ysl[0] + 300), (xsl[1] + 300, ysl[1] + 300))
            pygame.draw.line(screen, 'black', (0, 300), (600, 300))
            pygame.draw.line(screen, 'black', (300, 0), (300, 600))

    pygame.draw.line(screen, 'black', (0, 300), (600, 300))
    pygame.draw.line(screen, 'black', (300, 0), (300, 600))
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What is your goal? So many close tangents look like a fill, do you need to skip some x-values so you can see the individual lines? E.g., change your tangent drawing loop to `for i in range(0, 600, 10):`

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're drawing a white line and then immediately drawing a blue line on top of it, so the white line is there but not visible. You can solve this using [pygame.Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)

Modified code:

```
import pygame
from math import *

pygame.init()

#Make screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

#Make a new surface
surface = pygame.Surface((600,600))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
fun = True
x = -300
y = 0
xl = [0, 0]
yl = [0, 0]
ys = 0
xs = -300
xsl = [0, 0]
ysl = [0, 0]
al = 0
slobe = 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    # Reset surface
    surface.fill((255,255,255))

    if x <= 300 and fun:
        if x == -1:
            x = 1
        yl[0] = y
        y = 0.001 * x**2
        y = -y
        yl[1] = y

        xl[0] = x
        x += 1
        xl[1] = x

        pygame.draw.line(surface, 'red', (xl[0] + 300, yl[0] + 300), (xl[1] + 300, yl[1] + 300))

    if x > 300 and fun:
        fun = False
        x = -300

    if not fun:
        y = 0.001 * x**2
        y = -y

        if x == -1:
            x = 1

        x += 1
        slobe = 0.002 * x
        xs = -300
        for i in range(600):
            point = (x, y)

            xsl[0] = xs
            xs += 1
            xsl[1] = xs

            al = xs + point[0]

            ysl[0] = ys
            ys = slobe * al + y + 3
            ysl[1] = ys

            pygame.draw.line(surface, 'blue', (xsl[0] + 300, ysl[0] + 300), (xsl[1] + 300, ysl[1] + 300))

    pygame.draw.line(surface, 'black', (0, 300), (600, 300))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, 'black', (300, 0), (300, 600))

    screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Should display like this
[image]